# how to get perticular words form String line

Tags: java

Hi I am not able to get perticular words form String line

```
  String text = "[1;24r[24;1H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[24;1HProcurve-1# [24;1H[24;13H[24;1H[?25h[24;13H";
```

above mention String contain i want only

> Procurve-1#

.
using regex pattern how to get it.

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: This example is not enough for understanding what you want! for example a pattern that matches this is the substring from i(47) to j(58). Is this good? What is the meaning of whole of that string and what are you looking for?

Comment: What you have tried so far

Comment: For getting a regex you have to define EXACTLY what the rules are for finding the word.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(Procurve-1#)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1)
}
```

[Regex1010 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL9hS4/1)